# Get checkbox for some option and Tree panel for some ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm kind of new to Extjs. There is something I would like to know. I have 6 columns. Each column is dependent on the previous one with the exception of the first one. Now data being shown in the second column is dependent on the first column.

Now I have a tree panel in the first column with checkbox from which if a checkbox is selected then the data will render in the second column which is a simple checkbox list. But now I would like render tree panel on some of the options and simple checkbox list on some. Can somebody tell me how can I accomplish that because I can't find anything.

*Model*

Here's how I'm doing it

```
Ext.define('modelClass', {
    extend: 'someClass',
    alias: 'viewmodel.modelClass',
    requires:['somemodel'],
    stores : {
        optionTypesOne:{
            type: 'tree',
            autoLoad: false,
            model:'some model',
            root: {expanded: true, "data": []},
            proxy: {
                url: 'xxx',
                type: 'ajax',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            },
            listeners:{
                load : 'callback'
            }
        },
        OptionTypeTwo: {
            fields:[some fields], // TODO create model
            autoLoad: false,
            storeId: 'xxx',
            listeners:{
                add: 'xxx'
            }
        },
        optionTypeThree: {
            fields:[xxx],
            storeId: 'xxx',
            autoLoad: false,
            listeners:{
                add: 'xxx'
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Now optionTypeOne is the first column optionTypeTwo is the second and otpionTypeThree is third and so on. Now can somebody tell me what should I do in the second column so that I can get treepanel on the options that I want and simple checkbox list on some.

**AND i'M USING eXTjS 6.0.2**

Thanks